# How to cast computed column with correct decimal/$ result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following computed column in sql server 2008

```
[Total] AS  CAST ( ((val1/(1000)) * [val2]) AS DECIMAL(18,2))  PERSISTED,
```

When val1 = 862500 and val2 = 8, the computed value = 6896.00

I need it to be decimal/money where (862500/1000) * 8 = 6900.00 (not 6896.00).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BOL says:

> Caution:   When you use the +, -, *, /, or % arithmetic operators to
>   perform implicit or explicit conversion of int, smallint, tinyint, or
>   bigint constant values to the float, real, decimal or numeric data
>   types, the rules that SQL Server applies when it calculates the data
>   type and precision of the expression results differ depending on
>   whether the query is autoparameterized or not.
>
> Therefore, similar expressions in queries can sometimes produce
>   different results. When a query is not autoparameterized, the constant
>   value is first converted to numeric, whose precision is just large
>   enough to hold the value of the constant, before converting to the
>   specified data type. For example, the constant value 1 is converted to
>   numeric (1, 0), and the constant value 250 is converted to numeric (3,
>   0).
>
> When a query is autoparameterized, the constant value is always
>   converted to numeric (10, 0) before converting to the final data type.
>   When the / operator is involved, not only can the result type's
>   precision differ among similar queries, but the result value can
>   differ also. For example, the result value of an autoparameterized
>   query that includes the expression SELECT CAST (1.0 / 7 AS float) will
>   differ from the result value of the same query that is not
>   autoparameterized, because the results of the autoparameterized query
>   will be truncated to fit into the numeric (10, 0) data type. For more
>   information about parameterized queries, see Simple Parameterization.

So, you need to convert [val1], 1000 and [val2] to float types:

```
[Total] AS CAST ( ((CAST ([val1] as float)/CAST (1000 as float)) * CAST ([val2] as float)) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) PERSISTED
```

Answer (score 4):

I came up with this:

```
SELECT  (cast(862500 as float)/cast(1000 as float) ) * 8  

returns 6900
```

To make it 2 decimal places....

```
SELECT  cast((cast(862500 as float)/cast(1000 as float) ) * 8  as decimal(18,2))

returns 6900.00
```

Your specific case:

```
[Total] AS  CAST ( ((cast(val1 as float)/(1000)) * cast([val2] as float)) AS DECIMAL(18,2))  PERSISTED,
```