# Change type of calculated field in select query (sqlite)

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

im sure i am not the first one to ask this but i can't find the answer to this:
I haver a select query on a datatable in a sqlite database.

```
select *, ((int_EndTime)-(int_StartTime))/60 as dou_usage_min FROM tbl_unautho_usage;
```

when i run this i get all the fields from the datatable including a new column calculated from to integer columns with unix time stamp values. However, i want my calculated column to be of the type double. With the query above i get a type integer.

```
select *, ((int_EndTime as float)-(int_StartTime as float))/60 as dou_usage_min FROM tbl_unautho_usage;
```

Afterwards  I tried  to change the column type of my integer-columns to float, but this gies me the following error:

```
near "as": syntax error:
```

i got the idea for that from the following post:
[How to cast computed column with correct decimal/$ result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802209/how-to-cast-computed-column-with-correct-decimal-result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try multiplying a value used within the arithmetic operation by `1.0`.

```
select 
  *, 
  ((int_EndTime*1.0)-(int_StartTime*1.0))/60 as dou_usage_min 
FROM tbl_unautho_usage;
```

Probably only one value multiplied will be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax of a [CAST expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr) is "CAST(*something* AS *type*)".

But in this case, for the division to be done with floating-point numbers, it is sufficient for at least one of the operands to be a floating-point number:

```
SELECT *, (int_EndTime - int_StartTime) / 60.0 ...
```